# Best way to split in Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have a name in this format `Doe, John`. What is the **BEST** way to change that into `John Doe` using javascript? would it be using the split function?

Comment: May be Using `String#replace`

Comment: Define "best" .

Comment: Most efficient.....

Comment: Why not try various ways (ie. write some code) and [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @programmerGuy How many times are you going to be doing it? Is every microsecond really critical to your application? [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Barmar  Best would be somewhere between Hilary and Donald

Comment: Why use word `split`? And you want to be the output is to reverse them?

Answer (score 0):

Fast coding:

```
"Doe, John".split(", ").reverse().join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your string to obtain a array inverse it and join it as a string like this :

```
var input = "Doe, John";
var output = input.split(",").reverse().join(" ");
console.log(output); // John Doe
```